# Post form without ajax in xml

Tags: jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc

Hi guys i'm working on MVC project.
i need to POST **xml** without Ajax call? how i can to do that? How i can post that? but i need only xml request without ajax.

```
<getAll xmlns='http://1111.ru'><list>true</list></getAll>
```

i was trying:

```
$("<form action='@Url.Action("GetAllShepherds", "Actions")'" + " content='text/xml' " + "<<getAll xmlns='http://1111.ru'><list>true</list></getAll>" + " method='POST'>" +
                 + "</form>").submit();
```

Is that real to submit form in XML request without ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML forms support [three enctypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype), none of which are `text/xml`.

There is no way for a site to make a POST request from a browser with a Content-Type other than those three without using the XMLHttpRequest object (except possibly by using a socket API and doing the entire thing by hand, but that would still be Ajax).